# "Unexpected identifier" error in Javascript when trying to parse JSON with escaped single quote

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, vue.js

In my Laravel application, I am passing a JSON object to a Vue component:

```
<search v-bind:library="'{{ json_encode(language_library()) }}'"></search>
```

`language_library()`, for testing purposes, returns just one line:

```
{"you_dont_have_subscription":"You don\\'t have an active subscription right now."}
```

As you see, the single quote in the string is escaped. However, Vue throws this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in

    '{"you_dont_have_subscription":"You don\\'t have an active subscription right now."}'

  Raw expression: v-bind:library="'{"you_dont_have_subscription":"You don\\'t have an active subscription right now."}'"
```

I don't understand why the issue is happening. It's a single quote inside double quotes and it's escaped too (using `addslashes()` in the PHP back-end). How can I have a string that contains quotes in my JSON, if not like this?

If, instead of addslahes, I manually do something like this...

```
str_replace("'", "\'", $string)
```

...I still get the same error, with two backslashes in front of the quote in JSON.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. What doesn't escape what?

Comment: you back backslash  backslash single-quote .... that escapes the second backslash, not the single-quote .... you have one too back backslahses ... ie. `\\'` escapes the second ```\``` not the `'` (finally wrote it out :p - damned backslashes)

Comment: That's the output of PHP's in-built addslashes function...I'm not manually adding the slashes. I don't understand why it would add two slashes and not one if it's counterproductive?

Comment: I get the same error if I don't use addslashes at all btw - then there's just the single quote with no slashes.

Comment: `That's the output of PHP's in-built addslashes function` - then PHP addslashes function is not what you need

Comment: No, I want you to start typing in real sentences :)

Comment: lol ... it's hard to highlight things with backslashes .... so, if you DONT use addslashes it fails as well? can you show the code that "creates" the output (where you use this addslashes function

Comment: See what I added to the end of the question...I just tried manually escaping the quote instead of using addslashes...but I got the same result with two slashes. And if I don't do anything to escape it, then there are 0 slashes. I guess the question is how to make it use one slash then.

Comment: What does `language_library()` actually return - is it an array or some PHP-native object, or is it the literal JSON string you put in the answer?

Comment: It is an array. It is turned into JSON on the spot with json_encode.

Comment: uses ` if makes sure **language_library()** will not return one text contains any ` .

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to write the `search` tag like in the below example:

```
<search v-bind:library="'{{ json_encode(language_library(), JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS) }}'"></search>
```

- **JSON_HEX_APOS:** *All ' are converted to \u0027*.
- **JSON_HEX_QUOT:** *All " are converted to \u0022.*

**EDIT**

Based on an example of [Laravel's Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade), you should remove the single quotes.

```
<option {{ $isSelected($value) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} value="{{ $value }}">
    {{ $label }}
</option>
```

So your search tag will become like this:

```
<search v-bind:library="{{ json_encode(language_library(), JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS) }}"></search>
// or you could declare a variable and assign `json_encode` to it
<?php $json = json_encode(language_library(), JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>
<search v-bind:library="{{ $json }}"></search>
```

Comment: Now the error is `avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "for"` - even though there is no `for` property in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

this is common mistake. its not about quotation, the double quotation make this error. why? see your input for prop

```
v-bind:library="'{"you_dont_have_subscription":"You don\\'t have an active subscription right now."}'"
```

it means js doesnt know why library prop ends with `v-bind:library="'{"` so use quotation instead of dbl quotation. like this:

```
<search :library='@json(language_library())'></search>
```

Comment: That produces SyntaxError: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Using the @json() directive in Blade is a Good Idea. BUT, it expects a regular PHP variable, so `language_library()` would have to return a PHP array, e.g. `["you_dont_have_subscription" => "You don't have an active subscription right now."]`.

Comment: I don't have the code on hand, but I strongly suspect using `@json()` on a string containing JSON would re-encode the JSON, and double-encoding is probably not what you need right here.

Comment: But `language_library()` does return a regular array, I'm sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

try it may work same thing happend with me some time

i use `{!!  $value !! }}`

```php
<search v-bind:library="{!! json_encode(language_library()) !!}"></search>
```

Comment: the sometime is happening because your object might contain ```'``` which compiled as closing string to your javascript, read my answer, you no need to have extra```'``` when echo raw blade to your javascript

Answer (score 0):

Answer: you **NO NEED** extra `'`

explanation:
remember `json_encode` will return `{}` and laravel will echo it as in `{{ }}` then passed and compiled to javascript as an object itself `{}`

edit:

with your extra `'` will treated as closing string by the javascript

example to your coding

```
<search v-bind:library="{{ json_encode(language_library()) }}"></search>
```

Comment: When I remove the extra `'`, I get `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`